# Why can't Microsoft implement CETAS export for SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, polybase

I wanted to export some data directly from SQL Server to Azure Blob storage in compressed orc format but there doesn't seem to be a way export like Azure SQL DW using CETAS Statement? I am wondering why Microsoft didn't include this feature in SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Any reason why my question is down voted? Just curious

Comment: It's not a question that can be answered by other users. If you want to know why MS did not or cannot include this feature in SQL Server, you'd have to ask them. You're better off asking how to accomplish something rather than asking for wild speculation on the whims of the gods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export data from SQL Server 2016 to Azure Blob using PolyBase by creating an external table and running an insert into statement.

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved my day

Comment: After doing number of testing I have found CETAS with insert into performs worst.